# DateTime TextFormField - Flutter and Firebase

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a TextFormField to recieve a date, and it works perfectly along with firebase. But when I choose a date, the chosen date doesn't appears on the screen:

[image: screen]

This is the TextFormField:

```
TextFormField(
            controller: saidadatecontroller,
            onChanged: (String datasaida){
              getSaidaName(datasaida);
            },
              autofocus: true,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 0, 12, 0),
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 138, 136, 136),
                fontSize: 18),
                prefixIcon: Icon(
                                Icons.calendar_month_outlined,
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 92, 172, 178),
                                size: 30,
                                ),
                              labelText: "Data da saída",
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 136, 136, 136), fontSize: 13),
                              enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                    color: Color.fromARGB(153, 191, 190, 190),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                    color: Color.fromARGB(153, 191, 190, 190),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            onTap: () async {
                              DateTime? pickeddate = await showDatePicker(
                                context: context, 
                                initialDate: DateTime.now(), 
                                firstDate: DateTime(2022), 
                                lastDate: DateTime(2036));

                                if (pickeddate != null) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    datasaida = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(pickeddate);
                                  });
                                }
                            },
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 21, color: Colors.black),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            cursorColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 87, 86, 86),
            ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the picked date appear as text in the `TextFormField` you have to set the text in the `saidadatecontroller`.

```dart
if (pickeddate != null) {
  saidadatecontroller.text = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(pickeddate);
}
```